# <xsl:number level="any"/> throwing error in XSLT 2.0 for generating a sequential counter

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, jdeveloper

I am trying to generate  a sequential counter in NOTLIN element. I am using <xsl:number level="any"/> for this but it's throwing error as internal error condition occured. I am using XSLT 2.0.
The <ORDER_NOTE_SEG> maybe get generated anywhere in xslt i want to generate a 4 digit sequential counter in NOTLIN element. Can anyone suggest how do i do this?
Here is the output i want to generate

```
<ORDER_INB_IFD>
   <CTRL_SEG>
      <ORDER_SEG>
         <ORDER_NOTE_SEG>
            <SEGNAM>ORDER_NOTE</SEGNAM>
            <ORDNUM>0839128278</ORDNUM>
            <NOTLIN>0001</NOTLIN>   
         <NOTTXT>abcde1abcde2abcde3abcde4abcde5abcde6abcde7abcde8abc</NOTTXT>
            <NOTTYP>ZZHU</NOTTYP>
         </ORDER_NOTE_SEG>
         <ORDER_NOTE_SEG>
            <SEGNAM>ORDER_NOTE</SEGNAM>
            <ORDNUM>0839128278</ORDNUM>
            <NOTLIN>0002</NOTLIN>
            <NOTTXT>abcde1abcde2abcde3abcde4abcde5abcde6abcde7abcde8abc</NOTTXT>
            <NOTTYP>ZZHU1</NOTTYP>
         </ORDER_NOTE_SEG>
         <ORDER_NOTE_SEG>
            <SEGNAM>ORDER_NOTE</SEGNAM>
            <ORDNUM>0839128278</ORDNUM>
            <NOTLIN>0003</NOTLIN>
            <NOTTXT>Z</NOTTXT>
            <NOTTYP>MTB_CHECK</NOTTYP>
         </ORDER_NOTE_SEG>
         <ORDER_NOTE_SEG>
            <SEGNAM>ORDER_NOTE</SEGNAM>
            <ORDNUM>0839128278</ORDNUM>
             <NOTLIN>0004</NOTLIN>
            <NOTTXT>X</NOTTXT>
            <NOTTYP>ORDER_COMBINATION</NOTTYP>
         </ORDER_NOTE_SEG>
      </ORDER_SEG>
   </CTRL_SEG>
</ORDER_INB_IFD>
```

**(Reinstated from original question by Michael Kay:)**

Here is my code

```
<xsl:template name="OrderNoteSeg">
    <xsl:param name="orderNumber"/>
    <xsl:param name="type"/>
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="0 to (string-length($text) - 1) idiv 60">
    <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
      <ORDER_NOTE_SEG>
        <SEGNAM>ORDER_NOTE</SEGNAM>
        <ORDNUM>
          <xsl:value-of select="$orderNumber"/>
        </ORDNUM>
        <NOTLIN>
    <xsl:number level="any"/>
        </NOTLIN>
        <NOTTXT>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($text, . * 60 + 1, 60)" />
        </NOTTXT>
        <NOTTYP>
          <xsl:value-of select="$type"/>
        </NOTTYP>
      </ORDER_NOTE_SEG>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to output the number as you iterate through the sequence of numbers?

Comment: I am trying to generate a counter as 1 2 3 4 5 in continuous sequence and not reset it after for-each iteration.

Comment: If it's an "internal error" then we need details of the error, and we need to know what XSLT processor/version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `xsl:for-each` loop the context item is a number, but `xsl:number` expects the context item to be a node.

You haven't said what you're trying to achieve so I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: I have edited my question with what i want to generate as a output.

Comment: You have also deleted your code, which makes my answer meaningless. Please don't edit questions in such a way that existing answers no longer make sense.

Comment: I've reinstated the code. You can achieve what you want, I believe, using `<xsl:number value="$position" format="0001"/>`. You could also use `position()` directly without a variable.